# NUnit constraint for delegate that does not throw a particular exception

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to test that a delegate does not throw `FooException`, but I don't care if it throws anything else. Therefore I can't use the `Nothing` constraint.

The constraints model doesn't have something like this:

```
Assert.That(del, Throws.Not.InstanceOf<FooException>());   //can't use Not like this
```

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Did you try to catch exception and verify that it's not instance of `FooException`? Something looks loke this: `Assert.IsNotInstanceOf<FooException>(exc)`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Yeah that's what I'm doing, but it's messy. I was hoping that there is a built in way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is slightly awkward but should do it

```
Assert.That(Assert.Catch(del), Is.Null.Or.Not.TypeOf<FooException>());
```

Personally, I prefer the two-line version

```
var ex = Assert.Catch(del);
Assert.That(ex, Is.Null.Or.Not.TypeOf<FooException>());
```

or the even clearer three-liner

```
var ex = Assert.Catch(del);
if (ex != null)
    Assert.That(ex, Is.Not.TypeOf<FooException>());
```

This works because not asserting at all is the same as succeeding.

The lack of a more direct way to test this in the syntax reflects an opinion of the developers - at least at the time - that you should always know what exception you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for all the different options! There's at least one case where you may not know, when you test guard/check statements. I know what it throws if the data is bad, but not otherwise (and don't care, only care about it responding in a particular way for the bad data).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like nunit does not provide it out of the box.
But you have some workarounds:
You may use additional assertion framework, like [`FluentAssertions`](http://fluentassertions.com/),
which allows you to do next assertion:

```
del.ShouldNotThrow<FooException>();
```

Also you can write your own [custom-constraints](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Custom-Constraints), like [`ThrowsNothingConstraint`](https://github.com/nunit/nunitv2/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Constraints/ThrowsNothingConstraint.cs)

Or you can just write custom metod

```
public void AssertException<T>(Action act) where T : Exception
{
    try
    {
        act();
    }
    catch (T e)
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Assert.Pass();
    }
}
```